# Check if JRadioButton is checked

Tags: java, swing, object, jradiobutton

I'm begining with Java and I'm having a simple problem, I wanna get wether my JCheckBox is selected or no. For this I know I have to use comboBox.isSelected(), but in the method I wanna use it, I cannot make reference to the object JCheckBox. Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class AgregarPlato extends JDialog {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            AgregarPlato dialog = new AgregarPlato();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public AgregarPlato() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 546, 459);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPanel.setLayout(null);

        JRadioButton radio = new JRadioButton("\u00BFDesea llevar Stock?");
        radio.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        radio.setBounds(91, 207, 168, 23);

        contentPanel.add(radio);

        {
            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
            buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
            getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            {
                JButton aceptarButton = new JButton("Aceptar");
                aceptarButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                        if (radio.isSelected()) {
                            System.out.println("It doesnt work");
                        }

                    }

                });
                aceptarButton.setActionCommand("OK");
                buttonPane.add(aceptarButton);
                getRootPane().setDefaultButton(aceptarButton);
            }
            {
                JButton cancelarButton = new JButton("Cancelar");
                cancelarButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        setVisible(false);
                    }
                });
                cancelarButton.setActionCommand("Cancel");
                buttonPane.add(cancelarButton);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the `JRadioButton` - The application does not contain a `JCheckbox`

The compiler does not allow non-`final` variables to be accessed in an inner class. Make the variable `radio` `final`

```
final JRadioButton radio = new JRadioButton("\u00BFDesea llevar Stock?");
```

Also `Swing` was designed to use [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). The application still has relatively few components so the transition to using one should be easy.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!

Also, I want to make a ComboBox which items have to be the results of a sql query, for example

SELECT name FROM category, and the ComboBox has to display all the names of that table, how would it be? 

Sorry, I'm brand new in programming and in Java!

Thank you so much again!

Comment: That sounds like the subject of a new post

Answer (score 2):

Declare your `radio` variable `final` or as a private member in your class and it will work.

`final JRadioButton radio` instead of `JRadioButton radio`